# gulp - internalBinding is not defined

Tags: gulp

I'm getting this error when I try to run the command `gulp watch-bs` for my [UnderStrap child theme](https://github.com/understrap/understrap-child) for WordPress. I've been using this command for a year with no problems, but I received this error today when I updated my *node* and *npm* to their latest versions.

```
ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined
    at internal/util/inspect.js:31:15
    at req_ (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\natives\index.js:137:5)
    at require (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\natives\index.js:110:12)
    at util.js:25:21
    at req_ (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\natives\index.js:137:5)
    at require (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\natives\index.js:110:12)
    at fs.js:42:21
    at req_ (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\natives\index.js:137:5)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\natives\index.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:99)
```

I've read [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246) that, in order to resolve the issue, I need to run this command:

`npm install natives@1.1.6`

but this did not help resolve the issue.

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as you.  To fix it, I added the following to my package.json in the devDependencies section

```
"natives": "^1.1.6"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Lloyd. I checked my `package.json` file and I can't see a `devDependencies` object anywhere in the file. However, I do have a `dependencies` object with `"natives": "^1.1.6"` as one of its properties. Do I need to run a command in order to have `devDependencies`? Thanks!

Comment: In your package.json, you can just add the devDependencies section.  https://npm.github.io/using-pkgs-docs/package-json/types/devdependencies.html

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot

Comment: Any comment on this warn from npm: "npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.". Should the solution be to install graceful-fs@4.x?

Comment: Working fine!! Thanks

Comment: Make sure to run "npm install" after making the change

Answer (score 20):

I had the same error after upgrading node to `v10.16.0`

I ran the following which solved my issue:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

After closer inspection, it would seem that the generated tree in package-lock was outdated.

Comment: If you are using yarn, just remove the yarn.lock file instead for package-lock.json

Answer (score 17):

I also faced the same problem and then I fixed by the following command:

```
npm install natives@1.1.6
```

May be helpful if someone having same issue.
updating node to latest version requires above package.

Answer (score 6):

I recently ran into the same problem after installing node. Similar to @Dv-Learner answer, What fixed it for me was:

```
npm install natives@1.1.6
npm rebuild node-sass
```

the bit about rebuild node-sass was required for my machine (Windows)

Answer (score 2):

@Student 22, in addition to Lloyd's solution, I simply updated my version to the most recent version for gulp using the command below ( Local Version 3.9.1 to Local Version  4.0.0) and I didn't run any additional commands.

**npm install gulp-update**

Reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24985

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I downgraded my node version from 10.16.0 to 8.11.4 which was required by my current project by this command

`sudo n 8.11.4`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error. Solved it by installing graceful-fs.

It seems that natives package is now deprecatd and you should install graceful-fs instead.

I had node v10.16.1 and glup local version 3.9.1. I ran 'npm install graceful-fs' and glup no longer gave the error in this question. 
(Can't comment yet, so an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me:

```
npm install -g graceful-fs graceful-fs@latest
```